# Get a list of tuples using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of time-related entites that are **point-of-time-centric**. E.g. each object 
PricesAtTimeX contains information about price of apples, price of banans for one specific point of time X.

Those I would like to transform to a JSON, more **timeline-centric** format using linq. E.g. an object BananaPrices that basically consists of a list of [date, value].

The concrete starting point PricesAtTimeX-class

```
public class PricesAtTimeX
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int BananaPrice{ get; set; }
    public int ApplePrice{ get; set; }
}
```

What I would love to make out of it:

```
[
    {
        "key": "BananaPrices",
        "values": [[date1, bananaPrice1], [date2, bananaPrice2] ... ],
    },
    {
        "key": "ApplePrices",
        "values": [[date1, applePrice1], [date2, applePrice2] ... ],
    }
]
```

My question is: **How to get a list of (int, int) with Linq** ?

---

My first attempt was to define a class that could be used to shell the data:

```
public class dataLine
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    // first tuple-int would be date converted to javascript datetime
    public List<Tuple<int, int>> values { get; set; }
}
```

.. and then try to fill that with Linq:

```
var result = from x in db.Prices
             select new List<dataLine>
             {
                 new dataLine() {
                     key = "ApplePrices",
                     values = ???
                 }
             };
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Another approach would be to pack all values into separate Lists..

```
var xValues = from x in db.Prices select new List<DateTime>() { x.Date };
var yBananas = from x in db.Prices select new List<int>() { x.BananaPrice};
var yApples = from x in db.Prices select new List<int>() { x.ApplePrice};
```

.. and then use the .Zip-method to merge each of the Prices-Lists with the Date-List

```
public List<Tuple<int, int>> TupleMe(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
    return list1.Zip(list2, Tuple.Create).ToList();
}
```

I'd be thankful for any suggestions, hints or ideas!

Comment: You are better off creating a simple class like `public class ItemPrice { public string Desc{get;set;} public double Price{get;set;}}` and then in your `PricesAtTimeX` class create a `public List<ItemPrice> Items{ get; set; }` then simply do linq like `var banana = PricesAtTimeX.Items.Find(i=> i.Desc =="Banana");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `Select` and using an `object[]` should do what you want.

Usually you would use a custom type, a `KeyValuePair` or a `Tuple` to group `Date` and `Banana`-/`ApplePrice` together (for typesafety), but since you're going to create a JSON string anyway, using anonymous types and a simple `object[]` is the easiest way to go.

```
var items = new []
{
    new PricesAtTimeX
    {
        ID = 1,
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3),
        ApplePrice = 10,
        BananaPrice = 20
    },
    new PricesAtTimeX
    {
        ID = 1,
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
        ApplePrice = 12,
        BananaPrice = 20
    },
    new PricesAtTimeX
    {
        ID = 1,
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
        ApplePrice = 14,
        BananaPrice = 10
    },
    new PricesAtTimeX
    {
        ID = 1,
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        ApplePrice = 17,
        BananaPrice = 7
    },
};

// maybe cache 'items' if you're running LINQ against a database
// and if you're not wanting to hit the database multiple times.
var result = new[]
{
    new 
    {
        key = "BananaPrices",
        values = items.Select(i => new object[]{i.Date, i.BananaPrice})
    },
    new 
    {
        key = "ApplePrices",
        values = items.Select(i => new object[]{i.Date, i.ApplePrice})
    },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

`json` is now (formatted for readability):

```
[
 {"key":"BananaPrices","values":[["2014-04-06T13:39:01.109062+02:00",20],["2014-04-07T13:39:01.109062+02:00",20],["2014-04-08T13:39:01.109062+02:00",10],["2014-04-09T13:39:01.109062+02:00", 7]]},
 {"key":"ApplePrices" ,"values":[["2014-04-06T13:39:01.109062+02:00",10],["2014-04-07T13:39:01.109062+02:00",12],["2014-04-08T13:39:01.109062+02:00",14],["2014-04-09T13:39:01.109062+02:00",17]]}
]
```

Comment: This looks perfect, it just gives me "Unable to cast type 'System.DateTime' to type 'SystemObject'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: Yes, this works only with LINQ-to-objects as it currently is. Since you query all items from the table, fetch and cache all items before doing the select. Something like `var items = db.Prices.ToList()`. This also makes sure that the database is queried only once.

Comment: It took a while, but I got it :o) Thank you VERY much, Dominic!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `let` to separete the logic of query in a sub-query and apply it on the result, for sample:

```
var result = from x in db.Prices
             let t = (from p in db.Prices select new { x.Date, x.BananaPrice, x.ApplePrice }
             select new List<dataLine>
             {
                 new dataLine() {
                     key = "ApplePrices",
                     values = t1.Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Date, t.BananaPrice))
                 }
             };
```